# Create new work item type using VSTS Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Based on the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/overview?view=vsts#what-makes-up-an-extension, a VSTS extension can be used to extend the work item form.

However, I would like my extension to automatically create a new work item type once it is installed. Is this something that is possible? I can't find any documentation online that suggests how to do it.

Comment: "I would like my extension to automatically create a new work item type once it is installed", do you mean create a specified new work item type for certain inherited process?

Comment: Yes, something along that line. I'm trying to create a hub extension that shows only items with this new work item type, so the project needs to have this work item type added to it first.

Comment: For this purpose, I suggest you **create the work item type manually and use the extension only to list work items with this type**. Since even you can create WIT through extesnion, but if you not click the hub after installing the extension, the event to create WIT won't be called, and you can not create work item with this type directly. Besides, update WIT for process is not supported by REST API, if you want to achieve the feature, you should use ajax request to achieve it (as jessehouwing said).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this is possible, the extension has a "first load" call which you can use to use the rest api to create a custom process or update the existing custom process. The REST Api to change processes isn't public yet, so you'll have to work from using fiddler to watch how the web ui does it.

Due to the way processes are linked to projects, all projects with that process will get the new work item type.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a lot of documentation online for this, but the VSS web extensions SDK(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vss-web-extension-sdk) has a REST client called 'ProcessDefinitionsRestClient' declared in the typings/tfs.d.ts file. This client has a createWorkItemType method available that looks like this:
     `createWorkItemType(workItemType: ProcessDefinitionsContracts.WorkItemTypeModel, processId: string): IPromise<ProcessDefinitionsContracts.WorkItemTypeModel>;`.

The 'ProcessRestClient' client has methods to create a new/inherited process to which the new WIT can be added.

I have not tried it out yet, and these APIs are still in preview, but maybe they can get you started on the right path.